# Registration email token outputted as link instead of plain address

Tags: rules, users, emails, tokens

I am using Entity Registrations for user registration to events on my Drupal 7 site. After the Registration i want to send an email to the registrant, with the Rules Module. So i need a token to get the recipients mail address. I tried

> [registration:user:mail]

and

> [registration:mail]

but i get the address with a link (example: "mailto:test@test.com"). Is there a way to get the raw value of the mail tokens out of this?